# XMind or MindMeister?

Tags: cloud, mindmapping

I'm considering buying the "Pro" version of one of these mind mapping applications to upgrade from FreeMind and store my mind maps on the cloud. Both of them support the file extensions of this latter.

Do you use any of the above applications? Which are their relative strengths and weaknesses? **XMind** has been recently awarded as [The Best Project for Academia](http://sourceforge.net/community/cca09/winners/) by SourceForge. **MindMeister** seems to have a nice [iPhone app](http://www.mindmeister.com/iphone) client. I think both of them look promising but which is the most customizable from a developer's point of view?

(please respond if you have experience with both these applications and know their differences)

Comment: This will get more attention on superuser.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Comparison of MindMeister and XMind

Both products are excellent and are rightly the market leaders in the cloud-based mind mapping market.

Through my own personal experience, I am more comfortable brainstorming with MindMeister. The iPhone application and offline access are two things I value highly.

**Be aware that the Pro version of MindMeister is $10 a year more expensive.**

---

## Mind Meister

[image]

- Create a mind map
- Share with friends
- Real-time collaboration
- iPhone App
- Offline uasage
- Real-time Brainstorming
- Highest security standards (256 bit data encryption)
- Mobile access
- Open Standards and APIs - Based on open source software, REST-based API for integration into other applications
- Access it anytime, Anywhere
- Full Audit Trail and map change history

#### Free Version

- Up to 3 mind maps
- Share and collaborate on maps
- Import from Freemind and MindManager™

#### Pro - $59 per year

- Unlimited mind maps
- Import and Export from Freemind and MindManager™
- Enhanced security
- Upload files and images
- Offline capability via Google Gears (Premium feature).

---

## XMind

[image]

#### Free Version

- Mashup Structures
- Mind Map
- Fishbone Chart (Cause & Effect diagram or Ishikawa)
- Spreadsheet
- Brainstorm and Fun
- Markers (image icons used to represent attributes on a map)
- Inline Notes
- Rich Text Notes
- Hyperlink/Attachments
- External files can be added to XMind maps as floating topics. Drag and drop from a user's local folder to a map.
- Easy to Use
- Drill Down and Drill Up
- Spell checker - automatically invoked as users type text into XMind
- Powerful Filter
- Import from Freemind/MindManager
- Export to Html/PNG/GIF/JPEG/BMP - (XMind is a fully-compatible solution with a wide range of third-party applications via Html/PNG/GIF/JPEG/BMP)
- Share With the World

#### Pro - $49 per year

- Designed for Business
- Brainstorming and Presentation - Full Screen Editor and a Timer
- Keyboard shortcuts and a hovering toolbar
- Security
- Gantt View
- Integration with Enterprise Environment
- Export to PDF(Text/Map)/Word/Powerpoint
- Export to MindManager and FreeMind
- Powerful Search to find content from Web and Workbook
- Improved Collaboration
- Privately Share
- MapShot - Take a snapshot of a specific region of a map and save it in an image file
- Map Merge
- Getting Things Done
- TaskInfo
- Gallery
- Design our own Theme

Comment: Initially I forgot to mention that I had used the software, which was specifically asked for in the question. I presume that was what someone took umbrage with.

Answer (score 3):

I can't vouch for XMind but I am a happy customer of MindMeister and it hasn't failed me.  Also, there is an API to MindMeister not matched by XMind... at least the last time I checked.

Comment: @Kensai: I have used both and I can safely say that MindMeister is more appropriate (at least for my needs): **with the API**, you are not stuck having to manually download all your files for **keeping a backup**. Futhermore, the collaboration features really work "real-time": the integration with Skype helps this.

Comment: hey, who down-voted my entry? I just realize that somebody did a "drive-by-downvote-without-an-explanation"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xMind free version and is everything what I need. So far not consider to Pro version, cause is not necessary for me to everyday use.